Python selenium: Impossible to close a frame using xpath or class_name
I'm trying to close a frame on this page.
What I want is to click in here:

It seems to be easy, but so far the following code (which should work) has failed:
import selenium.webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.bvc.com.co/variable-income-local-market/cemargos?tab=issuer-information')

#X(close) bvc frame
xpath = '//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/span'
class_name = 'sc-843139d2-14 iVPGqd'

# Trying with XPath
if 1:
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath))).click()
    except:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath).click()

# Trying with class_name
if 1:
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, class_name))).click()
    except:
        driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, class_name).click()

The output using XPath:
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
#0 0x64a95375031a <unknown>
...

The output using class_name:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".sc-843139d2-14 iVPGqd"}


this is not a valid css selector (well it sort of is but you don't want that), try .sc-843139d2-14.iVPGqd

@folengateis It returns: selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector from javascript error: {"status":32,"value":"An invalid or illegal selector was specified"}

sorry i really meant By.CSS_SELECTOR and not class name

You refer to "frame" in the question.  Is the button actually inside of a <frame> element?

when you do
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'sc-843139d2-14 iVPGqd')

selenium translates (poorly, by adding one dot) your class name into a selector, so it becomes
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.sc-843139d2-14 iVPGqd')

which means: find a iVPGqd tag (yes tag) contained within something with a class sc-843139d2-14. you don't want that. if you want to specify two classes for the same element you must collate them with no spaces between and use the proper locator CSS_SELECTOR
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.sc-843139d2-14.iVPGqd')


A simple way to close that popup is to click the 'X'. You can do that using the XPath below,
//span[text()='X']


You need to raise the WebDriverWait value, because 10 seconds is not enough, try raising it to 30 seconds and then reducing it until you find the minimum that works. If the element is not located, try to use this path:
//span[text()='X']

